# Выполнить анимацию css из javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3, css-animation

Есть такого рода анимация:

```js
var load = document.querySelector('.loading');

load.addEventListener('click', function listnerForClick() {
  load.style.animationName = 'navRightAnimationOnLoadingArts';
});
```

```css
.loading {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  //animation-name: navRightAnimationOnLoadingArts  
  -webkit-animation-duration: 300ms;
  animation-duration: 300ms;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 4;
  animation-iteration-count: 4;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes navRightAnimationOnLoadingArts {
  to {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px deeppink) drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px deeppink);
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px deeppink) drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px deeppink);
  }
}

@keyframes navRightAnimationOnLoadingArts {
  to {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px deeppink) drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px deeppink);
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px deeppink) drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px deeppink);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loading"></div>
```

Чтобы начать анимацию, можно просто вписать `animation-name: navRightAnimationOnLoadingArts` при помощи js, что я, собственно, и делаю.
Но как быть в случае, если нужно несколько раз воспроизводить анимацию?

Несколько не жестких условий:

- Необходимо воспроизводить её только когда происходит клик по диву.
- Анимация не должна перекрывать друг друга (это на случай, если
  предложите таймер в решении - учтите, что по диву можно будет
  кликнуть много раз, то есть анимация может быть вызвана несколько раз
  пока она воспроизводится).

Что я хочу сказать: [codepen](http://codepen.io/VostokSisters/pen/QpgKXM) - ***это не решение***.

Answer (score 3):

Ладно, уже сам разобрался. Решение было простым.  Сделал **2 варианта:**

---

### Через таймер, но с переменной для отслеживания состояния анимации.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/VostokSisters/pen/Qpgdwz)

```js
'use strict';

var load = document.querySelector('.loading');
var isAnimationPlaying = false;

load.addEventListener('click', function listnerForClick() {
  if (isAnimationPlaying) return;
  load.style.animationName = 'navRightAnimationOnLoadingArts';
  isAnimationPlaying = true;
  setTimeout(function () {
    load.style.animationName = '';
    isAnimationPlaying = false;
  }, 1200);
});
```

```css
.loading {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 300ms;
          animation-duration: 300ms;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
          animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
          animation-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 4;
          animation-iteration-count: 4;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
          animation-direction: alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes navRightAnimationOnLoadingArts {
  to {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px deeppink) drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px deeppink);
            filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px deeppink) drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px deeppink);
  }
}

@keyframes navRightAnimationOnLoadingArts {
  to {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px deeppink) drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px deeppink);
            filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px deeppink) drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px deeppink);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loading"></div>
```

---

### С использованием jQuery навесить на блок листнер на конец анимации.

Он мне нравится больше.
[codepen](http://codepen.io/VostokSisters/pen/OpgWrq)

```js
'use strict';

var load = document.querySelector('.loading');

load.addEventListener('click', function listnerForClick() {
  load.style.animationName = 'navRightAnimationOnLoadingArts';
});

$(load).on("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend MSAnimationEnd", function() {
  load.style.animationName = '';
});
```

```css
.loading {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 300ms;
  animation-duration: 300ms;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 4;
  animation-iteration-count: 4;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes navRightAnimationOnLoadingArts {
  to {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px deeppink) drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px deeppink);
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px deeppink) drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px deeppink);
  }
}

@keyframes navRightAnimationOnLoadingArts {
  to {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px deeppink) drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px deeppink);
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px deeppink) drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px deeppink);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="loading"></div>
```